# Oauth header issue with twitter api 1.1

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

I've been trying to access the new twitter api (1.1) for 3 days now, the new oauth system and i are not compatible. I only want to grab 3 of my latest tweets (which are public so why the need for oauth over simple rss is annoying)

```
<?php

$header = 'GET /statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=NAME&count=3&include_rts=false HTTP/1.1
Host: https://www.twtter.com:443
Authorization: OAuth realm="https://https://www.twtter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json",
    oauth_consumer_key="key",
    oauth_token="mytoken",
    oauth_nonce="",
    oauth_timestamp="0",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_version="1.0",
    oauth_signature="O4yJhqnYlxMP5U97rJ%2F4UuLjh84%3D"';

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=NAME&count=3&include_rts=false";

$options = array( 
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
        );

        $feed = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
        $json = curl_exec($feed);
        curl_close($feed);
?>
```

The header seems to be the problem ( i generated it using: http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/authentication/ )

NAME, MYTOKEN, KEY are placeholders for posts' sake.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: Try removing the `GET /statuses...`-line from your `$header`. Edit: and the `Host: ...` line too.

Comment: Nope nothing changed.

Comment: Hmm well the nonce must be unique in each request, and the timestamp must be current (so 0 is way to long in the past). I got it working with a current timestamp and a nonce (you have to calculate a new signature of course).

Comment: Well on second thought I suggest you use a OAuth-Library for PHP. It makes things so much easier. Have a look at https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth and the PHP example under https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples

Comment: Yeah thanks, ill just use a library.

Comment: +1 for the link (http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/authentication/); stepping through things like that is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use. Just call `returnTweet()`

For more info about 'user_timeline', visit [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

```
function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}    

function returnTweet(){
        $oauth_access_token         = "xxx";
        $oauth_access_token_secret = "xxx";
        $consumer_key               = "xxx";
        $consumer_secret            = "xxx";

        $twitter_timeline           = "user_timeline";  //  mentions_timeline / user_timeline / home_timeline / retweets_of_me

        //  create request
            $request = array(
                'trim_user'     => 1,
                'screen_name'   => 'budidino',
                'count'         => '3'
            );

        $oauth = array(
            'oauth_consumer_key'        => $consumer_key,
            'oauth_nonce'               => time(),
            'oauth_signature_method'    => 'HMAC-SHA1',
            'oauth_token'               => $oauth_access_token,
            'oauth_timestamp'           => time(),
            'oauth_version'             => '1.0'
        );

        //  merge request and oauth to one array
            $oauth = array_merge($oauth, $request);

        //  do some magic
            $base_info              = buildBaseString("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/$twitter_timeline.json", 'GET', $oauth);
            $composite_key          = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
            $oauth_signature            = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
            $oauth['oauth_signature']   = $oauth_signature;

        //  make request
            $header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
            $options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                              CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                              CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/$twitter_timeline.json?". http_build_query($request),
                              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

            $feed = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
            $json = curl_exec($feed);
            curl_close($feed);

        return json_decode($json, true);
    }
```

I hope it helps ;)